# Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo un error que no puedo solucionar ya que me sale este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que ocurre es cuando cambio de componente mediante un `switch` en donde dependiendo `true` o `false` se muestra, en este caso reemplazo toda la vista y es donde sale este error

**Componente**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Fecha from "./Fecha";
import { Scrollbars } from 'react-custom-scrollbars';
import { Totales } from "./Metodos";
import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group';
export default class Orden extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state={isMounted:false}
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({isMounted:!this.state.isMounted});
    }
    componentWillUnmount(){
        this.setState({isMounted:!this.state.isMounted});
    }
    procesa(){        
        this.props.procesa();
    }
    remove(i){
        this.props.remove(i);
    }
    cantidad(e,i){
        var a = (i.target.value).replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
        if (a!="" && a > 0){
            this.props.cantidad(e, i.target.value);
        }else{
            alertify.error("Ingrese un numero mayor a '0'");
        }        
    }
    cancelar(){
        this.props.cancelar();
        alertify.error("Cancelado");
    }
    render() {
        const data = this.props.orden.map((item, i) =>
            <tr key={i} className="animated">
                <td className="align-middle">
                    <div id="detalle">
                        <span className="descripcion">{item.descripcion}</span><br />
                        {item.color[item.co].Descripcion} | {item.talla[item.ta].Descripcion}
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td className="text-right align-middle">{item.moneda.symbol}{item.PVP}</td>
                <td className="align-middle">
                    <div id="cantidad">
                        <input value={item.cantidad} onChange={this.cantidad.bind(this, i)} type="number" min="1"/>
                        <div id="div">
                            <div id="inc-button" className="spinner-button"></div>
                            <div id="dec-button" className="spinner-button"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td className="text-right align-middle">{item.moneda.symbol}{item.total}</td>
                <td className="align-middle"><span onClick={this.remove.bind(this,i)} style={{ fontSize:"1.3rem" }}><i className="fas fa-times"></i></span></td>
            </tr>
        );
        return (
            <div id="orden">
                <div className="ocab">
                    Detalle de Compra
                    <span onClick={this.cancelar.bind(this)}>CANCELAR <i className="fal fa-trash-alt fa-2x"></i></span>
                    {this.state.isMounted ? <Fecha />:''}
                </div>
                <Scrollbars id="otable" className="animated bounceIn">
                    {this.state.isMounted ? <table className="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th><span className="thproducto">PRODUCTO</span></th>
                                <th className="text-right align-middle">PRECIO</th>
                                <th>CANTIDAD</th>
                                <th className="text-right align-middle">SUBTOTAL</th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
                                    component={React.Fragment}
                                    transitionName="example"
                                    transitionEnterTimeout={700}
                                    transitionLeaveTimeout={700}
                                >
                                    {data}  
                                </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>                          
                            </tbody>
                    </table>:''}
                </Scrollbars>
                <div className="footer col-md-4">
                    {this.state.isMounted ? <Totales 
                        total={this.props.total}
                        subtotal={this.props.subtotal}
                        descuento={this.props.descuento}
                        igv={this.props.igv}
                    />: ''}
                    <div className="text-center align-middle">
                        <button onClick={this.procesa.bind(this)} className="btn btn-secondary">PROCESAR ORDEN</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

He buscado otras formas de hacerlo pero no funcionan

```
_isMounted = false
```

pero con esto me sale este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

el error te lo está proporcionando la siguiente línea seguramente:

```
componentWillUnmount(){
    this.setState({isMounted:!this.state.isMounted});
}
```

Lo que ocurre es que cuando reemplazas la vista a través del `Switch`, el componente se "desmonta". Fíjate que **estás lanzando un `setState` sobre el propio componente que se va a desmontar**. Por lo que React no es capaz de realizarlo ya que el componente ya no existe.

El uso común de `componentWillUnmount` es para eliminar eventos o referencias del DOM que si se volviera a montar el componente se duplicarían o para cortar request en vuelo de peticiones HTTP, por ejemplo.

Espero que se entienda y te sirva, saludos.